# implementing non-blocking timed operations - without delay() - for Arduino

Tags: arduino, delay

First off, very new to Arduino and I have scoured tutorials in an effort to make this work and nothing has seemed to help me. What I am trying to do is have an LCD backlight activate for 8 seconds when a button is pushed.

I have had minor success with my first attempt at the code:

```
const int buttonPin = 13;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  9;      // the number of the LED pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void timeDelay(){

digitalWrite (ledPin, HIGH);
delay(8000);
digitalWrite (ledPin, LOW); 

}


void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);
    // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    // turn LED on:
    timeDelay();
}
}
```

This works great, I push the button and it calls the script, the only problem is that it puts everything else on pause. It seems that I need to implement a solution using the `millis' but everything I have seen works off the BlinkWithoutDelay sketch and I cannot seem to make that happen.

Any advice or relevant tutorials would be great.

EDIT:

I'd like to thank pirho for the explanation below. This was the code I was able to make work thanks to their guidance:

```
// constants won't change. Used here to set a pin number :
const int ledPin = 9;// the number of the LED pin
const int buttonPin = 13;     // the number of the pushbutton pin

// Variables will change :
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status


// Generally, you should use "unsigned long" for variables that hold time
// The value will quickly become too large for an int to store
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated
unsigned long currentMillis = 0;
unsigned long ledTimer = 0;

// constants won't change :
const long interval = 8000;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)


void setup() {
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
//  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // here is where you'd put code that needs to be running all the time.
 currentMillis = millis();
 buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
 ledTimer = (currentMillis - previousMillis);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite (ledPin, HIGH);
    previousMillis = millis();
}

    if (ledTimer >= interval) {
      // save the last time you blinked the LED
      digitalWrite (ledPin, LOW);
      } else {
        digitalWrite (ledPin, HIGH);
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,`delay(8000);` in your `void timeDelay() {...}` blocks the loop.

To change it unblocking you must in the loop, in each round:

- if btn pressed store the pressMillis, lit the led
- compare if currentMillis-pressMillis > 8000, if then shut the led
- do the other actions

Hope this was not too abstract but not going to write the code for you ;)

Note also that the checks could be optimized based on led state but it might not bring any performance change just a check instead of io write and extra code, possibly.

UPDATE: also some multi threading libraries like [ProtoThreads](https://code.google.com/archive/p/arduino-class/wikis/ProtoThreads.wiki) can be used. Depending on programming skills and complexity of program/count of parallel tasks such might be good choice also but not necessarily.

Search this site for `arduino thread`

Comment: Thanks, that actually was very helpful when you broke it down. I posted the final code I was able to make work. Thanks again for the help!